# How to change the state variable as true based on index value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when i clicked on close button the val will immedietly changes to Fruit. how to do that?
for example

```
    Apple          close
    Grapes         close
    Pineapples     close
```

otherwise how can we set the state cancel is true based on the index.
I mean if i clicked on Apple close button, only that index value will true other are false. can we do this?

here is the sample code

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
        cancel: false;
    }
}

<table>
        <tr>
            {
                products.map((val, index)=>{
                    <td>{val} &nbsp; <button>closeIcon</button></td>
                });
            }
        </tr>
    </table>
```

`if anyone help me how to solve this problem`

1. Here i have asked two questions.

   ```
    Outof these you can answer one question.
   ```

Comment: I don't completely understand what you want, but if you just want to remove the item when close button is clicked, see my answer below (the jsFiddle link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for, only one fruit can be closed

```
export default class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      cancel: false,
      products: [
        {
          name: "Apple",
          closed: false
        },
        {
          name: "Grapes",
          closed: false
        },
        {
          name: "Pineapples",
          closed: false
        }
      ]
    };
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onClick(e) {
    this.setState((s) => ({
      ...s,
      products: s.products.map((p) => ({
        ...p,
        closed: p.name === e.target.name
      }))
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tr>
          {this.state.products.map((val, index) => {
            return (
              <td>
                {val.closed ? "CLOSED" : "OPEN"} {val.name} &nbsp;{" "}
                <button name={val.name} onClick={this.onClick}>
                  closeIcon
                </button>
              </td>
            );
          })}
        </tr>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

Take a look https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-swirles-wfnks?file=/src/App.js

To make all can close:

```
onClick(e) {
    this.setState((s) => ({
      ...s,
      products: s.products.map((p) =>
        p.name === e.target.name ? { ...p, closed: true } : p
      )
    }));
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-glade-6vg6b

Comment: yes, you are correct but if i clicked on Apple button it will close. Then after i clicked on Banana button Banana also should display close. I mean now Apple and Banana has closed and other are Still same

Comment: I thought thats what you meant by "I mean if i clicked on Apple close button, only that index value will true other are false"

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: yes, then again if i clicked on some other fruits let's say Banana, the apple has already false and let it be false. as well as the Banana also should false. Simply say, if i clicked on any fruit, the fruit will go to false

Comment: Yes, It looks perfect I want. Thank u so much for helping

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a seperate state for Button component in that is being rendered by map. In this way you'll be able to setState for every individual Button component.
Wrap your button in a seperate component

```js
export default class ButtonComponent extends React.Component{
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
        cancel: false;
    }
}

onCancel = () => {
this.setState({...this.state, cancel: true})
}
render(){
  return(
    <td>{val} &nbsp; <button onClick={this.onCancel}>closeIcon</button>
    </td>

  )
}

}
```

```js
render(){
  return(
    <table>
            <tr>
                {
                    products.map((val, index)=>{
                        <ButtonComponent key={index} />
                    });
                }
            </tr>
        </table>
  )
}
```

Comment: If we do like this all the filed will goes to true.Right?

Comment: for every button to only set its own setState, break down Parent Component. In this example break your button in to another component and give it a seperate state

Comment: var products= [{
     "fruit": "Apple"
   }, {
     "fruit": "Grapes"
   }, {
     "fruit": "Pineapple"
   }, {
     "fruit": "Banana"
   }]

Comment: I hv sent product list. can u run the code once ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the anything from your map function. After fixing it, simply updating the state with `this.setState` on `onClick` would do

```
 <tr>
            {
                products.map((val, index)=>{
                    return (<td>{val} &nbsp; <button>closeIcon</button></td>);
                });
            }
 </tr>
```

See the jsfiddle here, https://jsfiddle.net/qzmu5307/

Edit: If you just want to remove an item from the list on close button, you can simply remove that item from the array in the state (**for now i am doing so by searching the value in the array, but this is usually a bad practice. Assign them some identifiers for this uprose**).